# Hadoop Error: Exception message: '/tmp/hadoop-user' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, windows, hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop, and I've been following a guide I found on LinkedIn titled "[Installation of Hadoop single node cluster and run simple applications like word count in Windows OS.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/installation-hadoop-single-node-cluster-run-simple-applications-k%3FtrackingId=ch0pwBKERUqzzOztP8EVIg%253D%253D/?trackingId=ch0pwBKERUqzzOztP8EVIg%3D%3D)" Everything was working fine until the end. However, when I ran the mapreducer.jar program to count word occurrences, I encountered the following error:

```
Exception message: '/tmp/hadoop-Arif' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
```

I have also confirmed that I can see the content of the input file.
This is the command I am using:

```
hadoop jar "C:\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.8.0.jar" wordcount /inputdir/input_file.txt /temp/output
```

I have also attached a screenshot of the command execution. I would really appreciate it if you could help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow official documentation and uses latest, stable Hadoop (3.x)
2. You need to fix your `hadoop.tmp.dir` config, at least, to be a Windows file path. Or you can run Hadoop in Linux VM or WSL2 or Docker, where you don't need to workaround (officially, undocumented) Windows modifications, as the Hadoop docs all assume you're using Linux only
3. No one really writes much mapreduce code anymore when Spark, Flink, Beam, etc all exist. You don't need HDFS/YARN to run these (not that you need them for mapreduce either, but it's the default mode)